# Solving system of ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on that problem, none of the examples provided match this type of question. How am I supposed to proceed ?

Solve the following system of ODE
\begin{align*}
\ddot x + 3\dot x - 2x + \dot y - 3y & = 2e^{-t} \\
2\dot x - x +\dot y - 2y & = 0
\end{align*}
with initial conditions $x(0) = \dot x (0) = 0$  and  $y(0) = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to convert the 2nd-order equations into 1st-order equations.  Let $z=x'$ and $w=y'.$  Then your first equation becomes

$$z'= -3z +2x -w +3y +2e^{-t}$$

and your second equation becomes

$$y'=-2z+x+2y$$

and since $y'=w$, you have $w=-2z+x+2y.$

Now you have the system of equations

$$x' = z$$
$$y' = -2z+x+2y$$
$$z' = -3z+2x-w+3y +2e^{-t}$$

Plug in the above expression for $w$ and you have a first-order system in 3 variables.  Note that $z(0) = x'(0) = 0.$  Proceed by covering up the $2e^{-t}$ and solving the homogeneous system first.  Then follow with variation of parameters (or undetermined coefficients) to solve the non-homogeneous version.

Comment: I don't understand how the new system of equation is any easier to solve ?